# WebAssembly emsdk installation fails

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, cmake, webassembly

I want to install [EMSDK](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk) for WASM compilation but EMSDK installation fails.

I've already installed Cmake (3.14.0-rc1 also tried 3.5.2 then) on Ubuntu 16.

When I run `./emsdk install sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit` it fails:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/emsdk/clang/fastcomp/build_incoming_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake invocation failed due to exception!
Working directory: /home/emsdk/clang/fastcomp/build_incoming_64
Command '['cmake', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python', '-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86;JSBackend', '-DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DCLANG_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF', '-DCLANG_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF', '-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=OFF', '/home/emsdk/clang/fastcomp/src']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Installation failed!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing make as cmake is complaining that there is no make program. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Or just `apt-get install make`